# how to generate data on the a given value of coefficient of multiple determination in R?

Tags: r, regression

I need generate data on the a given value of coefficient of multiple determination.
For example,if i indicated R^2 = 0.77,  i want generate data, which create regression model with R^2=0.77

but these data must be in a certain range. For example, sample= 100 and i need 4 variables(x1 - dependent var), where values in range from 5-15. How do that?
I use optim

```
optim(0.77, fn, gr = NULL,
      method = c("Nelder-Mead", "BFGS", "CG", "L-BFGS-B", "SANN",
                 "Brent"),
      lower = 5, upper = 15,
      control = list(), hessian = FALSE)
```

but i don't know how create function `fn` for my purpose. Please help to write this function

Comment: 4 variables. So a model with three predictors and one outcome?

Comment: `fn` needs to be a function you create that runs the regression on your parameters and returns the r-squared value. The thing about optim is that it either maximizes more minimizes (depending on the numerical sign of your returned value). So you should put some manual "restraint" to stop optim once it hits 0.77 on the r-squared. Something like `if(r2 >= 0.77) r2 <- 0.77`, forcing optim to stop after a few iterations because nothing changes. You also need to put your 4 parameters in the first argument in a list, not 0.77.

Comment: Andrew Taylor,yes!
giraffehere, could you show it on code, please.

Comment: @giraffehere Exactly what parameter(s) are you optimizing here? Are you leaving all 100*4 variables free?

Comment: @MrFlick I believe he's trying to generate 4 sets of 100 random variables ranging between 5-15 and having 3 of those sets regressed against the 4th set to have an r-squared of 0.77. Which, now that I say that out loud, could be extremely tedious and time consuming. I was more explaining how to use `optim`. He could have it generate line by line and the overall result should still be 0.77. I'm going to try attempting this later, but can't right now.

Answer (score 4):

First here's a solution:

```
library(mvtnorm)

get.r <-  function(x) c((x+sqrt(x**2+3*x))/(3),(x-sqrt(x**2+3*x))/(3))

set.seed(123)
cv <- get.r(0.77)[1]
out <- rmvnorm(100,sigma=matrix(c(1,cv,cv,cv,cv,1,cv,cv,cv,cv,1,cv,cv,cv,cv,1),ncol=4))
out1 <- as.data.frame(10*(out-min(out))/diff(range(out))+5)

range(out1)
# [1]  5 15

lm1 <- lm(V1~V2+V3+V4,data=out1)

summary(lm1)
# Call:
#   lm(formula = V1 ~ V2 + V3 + V4, data = out1)
# 
# Residuals:
#   Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
# -1.75179 -0.64323 -0.03397  0.64770  2.23142 
# 
# Coefficients:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)  0.36180    0.50940   0.710 0.479265    
# V2           0.29557    0.09311   3.175 0.002017 ** 
# V3           0.31433    0.08814   3.566 0.000567 ***
# V4           0.35438    0.07581   4.674 9.62e-06 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 0.927 on 96 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.7695,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.7623 
# F-statistic: 106.8 on 3 and 96 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Now let me explain how I got there. We can construct this statistically.  First we need to understand a little about correlation and covariance.  One formula for correlation is

> Corr(X, Y) = Cov(X,Y)/sqrt(Var(X)Var(Y))

And one formula for covariance is:

> Cov(X,Y) = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)

In your question you want to get the multiple correlation of the regression model:

> Y = X1 + X2 + X3

Let's make this as simple as possible and force the variance of all variables to be 1 and let's make the pairwise correlation between any two variables to be equal and call it r.

Now we're looking for the square of the correlation between Y and X1 + X2 + X3, which is:

> R^2 = [Cov(Y,X1 + X2 + X3)]^2/[Var(Y)Var(X1 + X2 + X3)]

Note that

> Cov(Y,X1 + X2 + X3) = Cov(Y,X1) + Cov(Y,X2) + Cov(Y,X3)

Further note that the variance of each variable is 1 and the pairwise correlation is r, so the above result is equivalent to 3r.

Also note that

> Var(X1 + X2 + X3) = Var(X1) + Var(X2) + Var(X3) + Cov(X1,X2) + Cov(X1,X3) + Cov(X2,X3).

Since the variance of each is 1, this is equivalent to 3 + 6r, so

> R^2 = 9r^2/(3 + 6r) = 3r^2/(1 + 2r)

We can use the quadratic equation to solve for r and get

> r = (R^2 +/- sqrt((R^2)^2+3R^2))/3

If we substitute R^2 = 0.77, then r = -0.3112633 or 0.8245966.  We can use either to get what you need by using `rmvnorm()` within the `mvtnorm` package.  And since R^2 is invariant to linear transformations, we can transform the resulting variables so that they fall between 5 and 15.

**Update:**

If we want to simulate with `n` predictors, we can use the following (note that I am not transforming the range of each predictor, but that can be done after the fact without altering the multiple R^2):

```
get.r <- function(x,n) c(((n-1)*x+sqrt(((n-1)*x)**2+4*n*x))/(2*n),
                         ((n-1)*x-sqrt(((n-1)*x)**2+4*n*x))/(2*n))

sim.data <- function(R2, n) {
  sig.mat <- matrix(get.r(R2,n+1)[1],n+1,n+1)
  diag(sig.mat) <- 1

  out <- as.data.frame(rmvnorm(100,sigma=sig.mat))

  return(out)
}
```

Comment: Very nice! two things you might add. 1) The data generated only has the specified R^2 on average, any individual sample may be different than the specified value. 2) You can always rescale variables to have a variance of 1 so this solution is more general than you make out. The only restrictive assumption is assuming all the covariances are equal.

Comment: @atiretoo Yes, rescaling variance is a possibility, but I was already too long-winded.  And yes, it only has the specified R^2 on average.  When I simulate data, that's how I roll.  These concepts can be expanded to include unequal variances and covariances, but this is a jumping off point.

Comment: The Biggest thank you.  Am I right understood, that, if i want use not 3 prediction vars, but 5, then this function will something like this
get.r <-  function(x) c((x+sqrt(x**2+5*x))/(5),(x-sqrt(x**2+5*x))/(5)) ?

Comment: And i forgot ask, what if values of vars have different range. For example dependent var has range from 1-10, and x2,x3 have range from 5-15 and x4 has range from 20-30. I would be grateful if you would show me how to work in such task.

Comment: Yes, your solution to the quadratic equation looks right. And you can change the range of the columns independently the same way I changed it for all of them:  `out[,4] <- 10*(out[,4]-min(out[,4]))/diff(range(out[,4]))+5`.

Comment: But Sam, if i do so
get.r <-  function(x) c((x+sqrt(x**2+5*x))/(5),(x-sqrt(x**2+5*x))/(5))
set.seed(123)
cv <- get.r(0.77)[1]
cv=0,57 
what's wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't paying attention.  We need to remember that Var(Y) is the sum of all the variances and the twice the sum of all the pairwise combinations of the Xs, so Var(Y) = 5 + 20r, which means we should use `get.r <-  function(x) c((2*x+sqrt(4*x**2+5*x))/5,(2*x-sqrt(4*x**2+5*x))/5)`.  So for 5 variables `get.r(0.77) = 0.80686`.

Comment: Sam ,what if i have 4 predictors,
so, we have 4+12r,right?
R^2 = 16r^2/(4 + 12r) = 4r^2/(1 + 3r),
so  out function,
get.r<- function(x) c((x+sqrt(3*x**2+4*x))/4,(x-sqrt(3*x**2+4*x))/4)?
i asked because didn't understand why if (1+2r)then function "x+sqrt"
and if (1+4r) (R^2 = 25R^2/(5 + 20r) = 5r^2/(1 + 4r)),then function "2*x+sqrt"
Sorry, i am still learning.

Comment: This is just quadratic function at this point.  With three predictors, Var(Y) = 3+6r (because there are 3 pairwise combinations).  With four predictors, Var(Y) = 4 + 12r (because there are 6 pairwise combinations).  With five predictors, Var(Y) = 5 + 20r (because there are 10 pairwise combinations).  In each case, we can pull out a factor from the numerator and denominator to simplify the expressions for the Corr(X, Y) to be: 3r^2/(1+2r), 4r^2/(1+3r), or 5r^2/(1+4r), for three, four, and five predictors, respectively.  In other words, we're solving for nr^2/(1+2(n-1)) = x.

Comment: Putting this into the quadratic equation, we can use `get.r <- function(x,n) c(((n-1)*x+sqrt(((n-1)*x)**2+4*n*x))/(2*n),((n-1)*x-sqrt(((n-1)*x)**2+4*n*x))/(2*n))`, where `n` is the number of predictors.  When we used three predictors, it simplified so that the first term was just `x`, but we couldn't simplify as far when we had five predictors because it started at `4x`.  I hope that makes sense.  I am going to add an update at the end to make it more general.

Comment: the biggest thank you. I understood)) You are very good  professional

Comment: Sam, i'm  sorry, but could you help me in this task
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34065615/how-generate-data-for-classification-tasks-in-r

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer, but I wanted to share what I did. I don't believe `optim` can be used the way you want it to. I attempted a "brute force" method to find a dataset that could work, but the highest r-squared I "randomed" was 0.23:

```
# Initializing our boolean and counter.
rm(list = ls())
Done <- FALSE
count <- 1
maxr2 <- .000001

# I set y ahead of time.
y <- sample(5:15, 100, replace = TRUE)

# Running until an appropriate r-squared is found.
while(!Done) {

  # Generating a sample data set to optimize y on.
  a <- sample(5:15, 100, replace = TRUE)
  b <- sample(5:15, 100, replace = TRUE)
  c <- sample(5:15, 100, replace = TRUE)
  data <- data.frame(y = y, a = a, b = b, c = c)

  # Making our equation and making a linear model.
  EQ <- "y ~ a + b + c" # Creating the equation.
  model <- lm(EQ, data) # Running the model.
  if (count != 1) { if (summary(model)$r.squared > maxr2) { maxr2 <- summary(model)$r.squared } }
  r2 <- summary(model)$r.squared # Grabbing the r-squared.
  print(r2) # Printing r-squared out to see what is popping out.
  if (r2 <= 0.78 & r2 >= 0.76) { Done <- TRUE } # If the r-squared is satfisfactory, pop it out.
  count <- count + 1 # Incrementing our counter.
  if (count >= 1000000) { Done <- TRUE ; print("A satisfactory r-squared was not found.") } # Setting this to run at most 1,000,000 times.

}

# Data will be your model that has an r-squared of 0.77 if you found one.
```

The issue with `optim` is that it optimizes individual parameters, single values. The first argument in `optim` is the `par` argument, which is meant to be a list of the values you want to optimize. This could be used in optimizing an r-squared by some decay function that is dependent on several values (these would be your `par` values). However, in this case, you're asking to optimize entire columns towards maximizing an r-squared, which doesn't make sense (as far as I know) with `optim`.